# C++ GUI Window position

Tags: c++, user-interface, window, position, command-line-interface

I have a GUi, written in C++/CLI . I want one specific window of it to open on a specific position (right top corner) of my display.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Which API? WPF, Windows Forms, straight up Win32 API? Do you have any code you can show? Have you tried anything? If yes, what problems did you encounter? These are all things you should consider before posting a question, if you expect a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowPos(
  __in      HWND hWnd,
  __in_opt  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  __in      int X,
  __in      int Y,
  __in      int cx,
  __in      int cy,
  __in      UINT uFlags
);
```

More info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/ -- That will teach you how to make a GUI for Windows only in window's native GUI implement (API).
To implement your code you need to respond to a user's action, i.e clicks a button then 
do i = 1+1;

Comment: i know and this wasn't the question ;)